# Differences calling FileStream.ReadAsync with / without await

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I decided to write a function for counting bytes in a file.

"Normal" and async.

So I wrote the following functions:

Function 1

```
public static async Task<int[]> ByteFrequencyCountAsync(string fname)
{
    // freqs
    int[] counted = new int[256];
    // buf len
    int blen = FileAnalisys.ChooseBuffLenght(fname);
    // buf
    byte[] buf = new byte[blen];

    int bytesread;

       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream
                                            (
                                              fname,
                                              FileMode.Open,
                                              FileAccess.Read,
                                              FileShare.Read,
                                              blen,
                                              FileOptions.Asynchronous
                                            ))
       {

          while ( ( bytesread = await fs.ReadAsync(buf, 0, blen) ) != 0)
          {

              foreach (byte b in buf)
                 counted[b]++;

          }
        }

        return counted;
}
```

Function 2

```
public static int[] ByteFrequencyCount(string fname)
{

    Task<int[]> bytecount = Task.Run<int[]>( () =>
    {              
        // freqs
        int[] counted = new int[256];
        // buf len
        int blen = FileAnalisys.ChooseBuffLenght(fname);
        // buf
        byte[] buf = new byte[blen];

        int bytesread;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream
                                            (
                                              fname,
                                              FileMode.Open,
                                              FileAccess.Read,
                                              FileShare.Read,
                                              blen,
                                              FileOptions.Asynchronous
                                            ))                                                            
        {

             while ( ( bytesread = fs.ReadAsync(buf, 0, blen).Result ) != 0)
             {
                 foreach (byte b in buf)
                     counted[b]++;

              }            
         }

         return counted;
     });
        return bytecount.Result;
 }
```

I think Function 1 executes reading asynchronously and Function 2 Synchronously.

Function 1

```
while ( ( bytesread = await fs.ReadAsync(buf, 0, blen) ) != 0)
```

Function 2

```
while ( ( bytesread = fs.ReadAsync(buf, 0, blen).Result ) != 0)
```

In short. I guess Task without await and not marked as async is executed over threadpool but Synchronously. So I can change fs.ReadASync for fs.Read and  nothing happens.

Need a hand, because I am a bit confused.

**EDIT1:**
Function 2 should be Synchronous so my questions about it:

Code works but I think using FileStream.Asynchronous has no sense.

I think using fs.ReadASync instead fs.Read has no real benefit. So it should be replaced by
fs.Read.

Comment: Thet are not the same. Just see return types. So `bytesread = fs.ReadAsync(......)` isn't compilable.

Comment: What are you asking?  I don't see a question here.

Comment: What is your question? Await keyword will release the current thread back to the caller and then pick up there again when the method completes. Without await you will not release the current thread and will execute synchronously

Comment: `Without await you will not release the current thread and will execute synchronously` No. Only you won't be waiting the result of the task while its executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just marking the method with Async does not make it so. Only when an awaiter is user will the method body execute in an asynchronous manner. You can see a great explination of how Async/Await works here [Async/Await under the sheets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_GTdR0gBVE)

Task.Run will execute in a blocking & synchronous manner.

The `FileStream.ReadAsync()` method returns an awaitable Task<> so it isn't useless. You don't have to await it if you don't want to but with a task you can also cancel it if needed.

have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158566%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for proper usage